# Iterating through dictionary for tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

This is more for clarification:

If I said:

```
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
```

This would actually give me keys and values rather than just each key being assigned to both "key" and "value"

It is just something that has always confused me about Python?

Comment: Is this even a question? The sentence that ends with a question mark is not something we can answer.

Comment: `.iteritems()` returns a tuple and by saying key, value in you're unzipping it into those two values

Answer (score 7):

For purposes of example the following two are equivalent:

## Example 1

```
for item in dictionary:
  print(item, dictionary[item])
```

## Example 2

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
  print(k, v)
```

However, in Example 1 you do not have direct access to the `value` of the item itself, only the key, whereas in Example 2 you do have access to it in the form of `v`.

## Terminal

```
>>> dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> for item in dictionary:
...   print(item, dictionary[item])
... 
b 2
c 3
a 1
>>> for k, v in dictionary.items():
...   print(k, v)
... 
b 2
c 3
a 1
```

And of course `k, v` are arbitrary as `k` and `v` can be anything, e.g.:

```
>>> for abc, xyz in dictionary.items():
...   print(abc, xyz)
... 
b 2
c 3
a 1
```